# Using Spark MLLib clustering (K-Means) for network anomaly detection

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a large set of network data which I have been using for clustering exercises with Spark and MLLib.  I've normalized the data to a set of vectors representing time of day, direction (into/out of network), bytes sent, bytes received, and duration of each connection.  There are seven dimensions in total.

Using KMeans, it is easy enough to build a model with this data.  Using this model, each input vector is "classified" and the distance is computed to the nearest centroid.  Finally, the RDD (now tagged with the distance) is sorted by distance and the most extreme values are extracted.

One of the input columns in my data is a connection uuid (unique alphanumeric identifier).  I would love to carry this data through the model (leaving each input vector uniquely tagged), but this triggers an exception when the column cannot be converted to a float.

The question here is: "how do I most efficiently tie the outliers back to the original input data?"  The input data is heavily normalized, and does not resemble the original input.  Further, the source and destination IP addresses have been lost.  I don't see any interface in KMeans to tell it which columns to consider (or, conversely, ignore) in building the model.

My code looks something like this:

```
def get_distance(clusters):
    def _distance_map(record):
        cluster = clusters.predict(record)
        centroid = clusters.clusterCenters[cluster]
        dist = np.linalg.norm(np.array(record) - np.array(centroid))
        return (dist, record)
    return _distance_map

def parseMap(row):
    # parses rows of data out of the input strings

def conMap(row):
    # normalizes the values to be used in building the model

rdd = sc.textFile('/data2/network/201610').filter(lambda r: r[0] != '#')
tcp = rdd.map(parseMap).filter(lambda r: r['proto'] == 'tcp')
cons = tcp.map(conMap)  # this normalizes connection data

model = KMeans.train(cons, (24 * 7), maxIterations=25,
                     runs=1, initializationMode = "random")

data_distance = cons.map(get_distance(model)).sortByKey(ascending=False)
print(data_distance.take(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since K-means is sensitive to outliers which means that anomalous data often ends up in clusters alone.

You need to count your data points by key(cluster) to find out the cluster that captured the outliers and filter out that points.